# How do I create and cancel unique UILocalNotification from a custom class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

Currently I have a timer with an alarm (local notification).

I want to create a timer class from this code to create multiple timers and notifications (at most 5) and I am struggling with how to create and cancel unique notifications with a class method.

```
- (UILocalNotification *) startAlarm {

    [self cancelAlarm]; //clear any previous alarms

    alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    alarm.alertBody = @"alert msg"
    alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: alarmDuration sinceDate: startTime]; 
    alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];

}
```

My assumption is that if I have a class method that creates a UILocalNotification called "alarm" iOS will see all of the notifications as being the same notification and the following method will not function the way I want it to:

```
- (void)cancelAlarm {

    if (alarm) {    
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:alarm];
    }

}
```

So I need a way to name these UILocalNotifications as they are created e.g. alarm1 alarm2...alarm5 so I can cancel the right one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could store them in an NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary (assigning a key to them) and release them by traversing the container.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer to your problem lies in the `userInfo` dictionary parameter that every `UILocalNotification` has. You can set values for keys in this dictionary to identify the notification.

To implement this easily all you have to do is have your timer class have an `NSString` "name" property. And use some class wide string for the key for that value. Here is a basic example based on your code:

```
#define kTimerNameKey @"kTimerNameKey"

-(void)cancelAlarm{
    for (UILocalNotification *notification in [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] copy]){
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        if ([self.name isEqualToString:[userInfo objectForKey:kTimerNameKey]]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
}
-(void)scheduleAlarm{
    [self cancelAlarm]; //clear any previous alarms
    UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    alarm.alertBody = @"alert msg";
    alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:alarmDuration sinceDate:startTime]; 
    alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; 
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.name forKey:kTimerNameKey];
    alarm.userInfo = userInfo;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
}
```

This implementation should be relatively self explanatory. Basically when an instance of the timer class has `-scheduleAlarm` called and it is creating a new notification it sets it's string property "name" as the value for the `kTimerNameKey`. So when this instance calls `-cancelAlarm` it enumerates the array of notifications looking for a notification with it's name for that key. And if it finds one it removes it.

I imagine your next question will be how to give each of your timers name property a unique string. Since I happen to know you are using IB to instantiate them (from your other question on the matter) you would likely do this in `viewDidLoad` something like:

```
self.timerA.name = @"timerA";
self.timerB.name = @"timerB";
```

You could also tie the name property in with a title label you may have.

Comment: Thanks so much once again! Very clear explanation, and a solid code example. Everything makes sense and it works like a charm. One thing I was curious about however was why it was necessary to copy cheduledNotifications.

Comment: @jemicha Glad I could help. To answer your question as to why it was necessary to copy the `scheduledLocalNotifications`, it's not. This is an example of my extreme paranoia. If apple ever exposes it's internal `NSMutableArray` of notifications, either through a policy change (so unlikely it's laughable) or a bug, then this copy would avoid possible problems. But again if you leave it out you will likely never see a difference.

Comment: Where you put ```dictionaryWithObject:self.name``` - how do you change ```self.name``` to a unique ID?