# How to remove local Notification in iOS for reminder

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, reminders

I am setting reminder in application for a particular time using local notification if i want to set five  reminder  i can easily done it. but if i wish to remove any reminder how will i remove notification for a particular time in iOS. please guide me any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are many questions on So that answers this question. Please search properly before posting new questions.Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232490/how-do-i-create-and-cancel-unique-uilocalnotification-from-a-custom-class or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158264/cancel-uilocalnotification

Answer (score 1):

may be this can help

- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification

read [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelLocalNotification%3a)