# Cancel single UILocalNotification

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I have several notifications on my app. What i want to do is to, when a local notification arrived, it erases another previous already showed one from notification center.

I am using the the following code.

```
static func unscheduleNotification(userInfoValue: String){
    if let notifications = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications{
        for notification in notifications{
            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String:String]{
                if userInfo["info"] == userInfoValue{
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone point me out the right direction here. If that is even possible.

Comment: see link in obj-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232490/how-do-i-create-and-cancel-unique-uilocalnotification-from-a-custom-class

Comment: That is what i am doing as you can see from my code but it is not working. For some reason.

Comment: If i use cancelAllNotification method it works as expected.

Comment: you can use break point to check your code

Comment: Yes i did and it is in fact running it but not clearning the notiication. Don´t know why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Or one solution. Adding one repetition interval to the notification allows with the method i was using and posted on the question to delete it.

I don´t know if it is the correct procedure or not but it is indeed working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive 1 notification when getting another 1, then best idea to keep you 1st notification object in `NSUserDefault`, when getting another 1 notification, fetch already stored notification from `NSUserDefault` then remove it.

Consider example if your device is restarted after receiving 1st notification. then it will be in notification tray but you would not get object to cancel it.

Also `scheduledLocalNotifications` will not provide object after restating your device. `scheduledLocalNotifications` doesn't work properly always with iOS 8.

Refer - [iOS 8 [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948037/ios-8-uiapplication-sharedapplication-scheduledlocalnotifications-empty)

While storing in `NSUserDefault` you have to convert notification object to NSData

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(notificationObject)
```

At the time of getting from `NSUserDefault` it will be NSData

So again convert to object

```
 let notificationObject : UILocalNotification = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? UILocalNotification
```